# Error Load JSON KendoUI Grid

Tags: jsp, grid, kendo-ui

Good Afternoon,

I'm doing the integration Kendo UI (JSP Version) in my application, but I'm having a problem with the integration of transport read on the grid.

The Grid could make the request normally.

return:

```
 {} && {"registros":
        [
          {
            "id":251,
            "matricula":"32849923",
            "status":true,
            "dataAdmissao":1361674800000,
            "dataDesligamento":null,
            "version":0
           }
         ],
        "total":1}
```

But the Grid could not render the data return. Below is my grid:

```
<kendo:grid name="grid" pageable="true" sortable="true" filterable="true" height="300">
                <kendo:grid-columns>
                    <kendo:grid-column title="Matricula" field="matricula" />
                </kendo:grid-columns>
                <kendo:dataSource pageSize="10" serverPaging="true" serverSorting="true" serverFiltering="true" serverGrouping="true">
                    <kendo:dataSource-transport>                
                        <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="${path}funcionarios" type="GET" contentType="application/json" dataType="json" />                
                    </kendo:dataSource-transport>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema total="total" data="registros">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                                <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="matricula" type="string" />
                            </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                        </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema>
                </kendo:dataSource>
            </kendo:grid>
```

- Request Information:

  - Request
  - URL:/qualitysoft/funcionarios?take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10
  - Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source
  - Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  - Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  - Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 Connection:keep-alive
  - Content-Type:application/json
- Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded take:10 skip:0

  - page:1
  - pageSize:10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that return is:

```
{} && {
    "registros": [
        {
            "id":               251,
            "matricula":        "32849923",
            "status":           true,
            "dataAdmissao":     1361674800000,
            "dataDesligamento": null,
            "version":          0
        }
    ],
    "total":     1
}
```

Do you mean that if you open in your browser that URL that is what you get? If so, the problem is that this is not a valid JSON retrieved file. If you change it to:

```
{
    "registros": [
        {
            "id":               251,
            "matricula":        "32849923",
            "status":           true,
            "dataAdmissao":     1361674800000,
            "dataDesligamento": null,
            "version":          0
        }
    ],
    "total":     1
}
```

then it works.

Comment: I really thought that too. I'm working on setting the Jackson in the project to verify that return.

Comment: I checked all the settings, but apparently that's OK. What I do not understand is why he is adding the invalid character. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339190/error-jackson-serialization

Comment: I did not try it with spring. I'll take a look into your other question and if I find something I let you know: boa sorte!