# Invalid JSON content generated by Spring Controller (using Jackson library)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

For some reason unknown to me, when making a request to my Spring controller it is returning an invalid JSON value. I'm using Jackson to map my JSON object. This is the data being returned when I make the request:

```
{} && 
{
    "registros": [
        {
            "id": 251,
            "matricula": "32849923",
            "dadoPessoal": {
                "nome": "Testando",
                "email": "tiare@terra.com.br",
                "telefone": "1235324812",
                "celular": "123832911",
                "foto": null,
                "salario": 3829
            },
            "status": true,
            "nascimento": {
                "dataNascimento": 1417485600000,
                "nascionalidade": "Brasil",
                "localNascimento": "SP"
            },
            "documentoPessoal": {
                "rg": "8329892332",
                "orgaoEmissor": "SSP/SP",
                "dataEmissao": 1417485600000,
                "cpf": "016.015.XXX-XX",
                "tituloEleitor": "adw91021",
                "zonaDeVoto": "91aa",
                "sessaoVoto": "2a",
                "enderecoVoto": "adw"
            },
            "dataAdmissao": 1361674800000,
            "dataDesligamento": null,
            "version": 0
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

The problem here is that somehow invalid characters "{} &&" are being added to the beginning of the JSON. What I'm not understanding is how? Its adding these values that are not defined anywhere in my Spring method.

My Request Mapping:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(VIEW_INDEX);

    view.addObject("registros", service.findAll());
    view.addObject("total", service.findAll().size());
    return view;
}
```

The Jackson configuration:

```
/**
 * @return MappingJacksonJsonView
 */
@Bean
public MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView() {
    MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setContentType("application/json");
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setObjectMapper(this.objectMapper());
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setEncoding(JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setPrefixJson(true);
    return mappingJacksonJsonView;
}

/**
 * @return ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
 */
@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
    List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    // Tiles
    viewResolvers.add(this.tileViewResolver());

    // Views 
    List<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    defaultViews.add(this.mappingJacksonJsonView());

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);
    contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(0);

    return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks you all. I found the error!!
When i started to read the javadoc i found this:

"Indicates whether the JSON output by this view should be prefixed with "{} && ". Default is false."

[springsource docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#setPrefixJson%28boolean%29)